# Append icon next to the link

Tags: jquery

I have two links i-e Previous and Next I want to show back icon for previous button and next icon for next button.
I am using Font Awasome's cdn to place the icons.
 My code is as follows:

```
$('span.CustomerDataPagerClass').find('a').each(function () {
            if ($(this).is('[disabled != disabled]')) {
                var str = $(this).text();
                if (str == "Previous") {
                    $(this).append("<i></i>").addClass('fa fa-chevron-circle-left');
                }
                if (str == "Next") {
                    $(this).after("<i></i>").addClass('fa fa-chevron-circle-right');
                }
            }
        });
```

Here my icons are getting addded but for both time its first adding icon and then link the but i want first icon then Previous link for previous button and for next button first link and the icon

Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: Your using chaining incorrectly or unknowingly, check @void's answer, should fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(this).append("<i class='fa fa-chevron-circle-left'></i>");
```

and

```
$(this).after("<i class'fa fa-chevron-circle-right'></i>");
```

Your code is adding the classes `'fa fa-chevron-circle-left'` to `$(this)` and not to `the appended element`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple method:

```
$('span.CustomerDataPagerClass a:contains("Previous")').append("<i class='fa fa-chevron-circle-left'></i>");
$('span.CustomerDataPagerClass a:contains("Next")').after("<i class='fa fa-chevron-circle-right'></i>");
```